# Getting width and height of images with JQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the width and height of images on one of my Django applications pages with JQuery. I use the JQuery .each method to loop through all the images on the page and log out the width and height of that image to the console. I know the .each method is working because I am also logging that images alt attribute, which shows up. When I use the width() and height() methods however, it just comes up as 0 and 0 in the console. Is there something I'm doing wrong here ? Does this only work if you have set the height and width of those images with css ?

Template

```
{% load inplace_edit %}

<section id="{{ section.label|slugify }}" class="sponsor">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sponsor-wrapper col-xs-12">
                {% for level in sponsor_levels %}
                    <div class="row row-centered">
                        <div class="ccr-sponsor">
                            <h3 class="sponsor-title">{% inplace_edit 'level.label' %}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row row-centered">

                        {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                            {% for sponsor in level.get_sponsors %}
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-centered">
                                    <a href="{{ sponsor.link }}" target="_blank"
                                       class="{% if sponsor.side %}wide{% else %}tall{% endif %}">

                                        <img src="{{ sponsor.image.url }}" alt="{{ sponsor.name }}">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% elif forloop.counter0 == 1 %}
                            {% for sponsor in level.get_sponsors %}
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">
                                    <a href="{{ sponsor.link }}" target="_blank"
                                       class="{% if sponsor.side %}wide{% else %}tall{% endif %}">

                                        <img src="{{ sponsor.image.url }}" alt="{{ sponsor.name }}">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            {% for sponsor in level.get_sponsors %}
                                <div class="silver-item col-centered">
                                    <a href="{{ sponsor.link }}" target="_blank"
                                       class="{% if sponsor.side %}wide{% else %}tall{% endif %}">

                                        <img src="{{ sponsor.image.url }}" alt="{{ sponsor.name }}">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}

                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>

    <script>
{#    $(document).ready(function () {#}
{#        $('img').each(function () {#}
{#            console.log($(this).attr('alt'));#}
{#            console.log($(this).width());#}
{#            console.log($(this).height());#}
{#        })#}
{#    });#}
    $(document).on('load', function () {
        $('img').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).attr('alt'));
            console.log($(this).width());
            console.log($(this).height());
        })
    });
</script>
```

Console

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change $(document).ready to $(window).on('load', function() { /* ... */ });

When you use ready the function is triggered when the whole DOM is loaded and processed. Using load triggers a function if the content on the website is loaded.

Comment: When I use the document.load function, it doesn't log anything at all.

Comment: The odd thing is that I did get the width and height of one image, the logo on the top left of my page, but nothing else.

Comment: I am sorry. $(document).on('load', function () { /* ... */ } ); I forgot jquery uses load as XHR shortcut.

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing :/

Comment: Last shot: $(window).on('load', function() { /* your code */ });

Comment: No problem, glad to help :). I am just sometimes confused about the whole topic with global events in a browser (window vs document).